# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy tratando de obtener los emails de una base de datos y a todos esos enviarles un mensaje esto es para un sistema de boletin pero cuando lo quiero ejecutar me sale este error:
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\reg\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\reg\index.php on line 3**

pero si esta definida y esta bien lla lo revise varias veces pero no se que es

```
<?php

$mi_conexion = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die('No se puedo conectar con la base de datos!');
   mysql_select_db('registros',$mi_conexion);

   $query_Tabla = "SELECT email FROM datos ORDER BY id ASC";
   $Tabla = mysql_query($query_Tabla, $mi_conexion) or die(mysql_error());

  $losemails="";
  while ($row_Tabla=mysql_fetch_assoc($Tabla)) {
   $losemails.=($row_Tabla['email'].", ");
   }

  $largo=strlen($losemails);
   if ($largo>2)
{
   $losemails=substr($losemails,0,$largo-2);
}
else
{
   echo "No hay destinatarios!";
   die();
};
$asunto='Prueba de email desde PHP';
$mensaje='<html>
<head>
   <title>Titulo de la Pagina</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Esta es una prueba de emails en formato HTML</p>
   Precios de nuestros productos:
   <table>
    <tr>
   <th>PRODUCTO<th>PRECIO<th>PROMOCION</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Refresco Grande</td><td>25,50</td><td>23,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Helado Napolitano</td><td>27,50</td><td>25,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Patatas</td><td>18,50</td><td>15,00</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>';

$envia='';
$remite='';

/*
Enviante: Nombre del enviante
Email_remitente: email que desea mostrar como remitente.
*/

mail(null, $asunto, $mensaje, "MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
From: $envia <$remite>
Bcc: $losemails" . "\r\n") or die("Error al Enviar el Email");
echo "Mensaje Enviado con Éxito!"; //

   mysql_free_result($Tabla);
   mysql_close($mi_conexion);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP tienes?

Answer (score 1):

El codigo que estas colocando es para la version de PHP antiguas y obsoletas lo mas seguro es que estas trabajando con PHP version 5.5+ , debes cambiarlo por seguridad ,de lo contrario te seguira mostrando el error , para solucionarlo debes colocar `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos")` eso es en cuanto a la conexion, para las demas sentencias te dejo [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) una referencia en la cual te puedes guiar .

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect esta deprecada desde PHP 5.5 y eliminada a partir de PHP 7.0, si estas corriendo un XAMPP con 7.0 el error es correcto, cambia la funcion a mysqli